# Where do I find the JSON response shape for the OAuth SalesForce endpoints?

Tags: salesforce

I'm reading [OAuth Endpoints](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_endpoints.htm&type=5), and I'd like to know what the response, both success and failure, looks like without making a test API call. Take for example

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
```

What does SalesForce return when calling this endpoint for both success and failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following URL has an example of a successful response [Salesforce OAuth](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_oauth_web_server_flow.htm)
It also means that the response varies based on which flow you use.

The documentation you provided explains that the token endpoint uses OAuth 2.0.
That means as a minimum the successful response will contain an access_token and a token_type as per [OAuth 2.0 Spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-5.1).

As an HTTP response (JSON encoded body), it must contain the following as a minimum:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Cache-Control: no-store
 Pragma: no-cache
 {
   "access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
   "token_type":"Bearer"
 }
```

That was the successful response, lets have a look at the error response as per [OAuth 2.0 Spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-5.2)

```
 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Cache-Control: no-store
 Pragma: no-cache

 {
   "error":"invalid_request"
 }
```

Important note, the status code can vary as explained in the second link.
You can also get an additional error_description and error_uri in the body.

Comment: Thanks, @jokk! For SalesForce, I also came across [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Errors](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_flow_errors.htm&type=5).